# Polarity of $\frac{x + 3}{x - 4}$

Tags: inequality, rational-numbers

This problem is giving me loads of confusion. I just need someone to walk through it because I have the answer and I can't get to it to save my life. I have been on it for days. Please help.

$$\frac{x + 3}{x - 4}\le 0$$

Comment: What are you trying to do? Find all satisfying $x$?

Comment: If you've been on it for days, then surely you must have tried inserting a few different values for $x$? Is the inequality satisfied when $x = 1$? What about $x = 10$ or $x = -500$?

Comment: I need to find all satisfying x values and express in interval notation.

Comment: Have you tried to plot the graph of the left hand side? This will give you some hints.

Comment: Is it any easier if you consider the related $(x+3)(x-4) \le 0\,$?

Comment: Yes that is an easier problem.

Comment: If you require $x \ne 4$ and multiply by $(x-4)^2 \gt 0$ then you get the *easier problem*.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hint:
Let "$+$" be any positive real number, and "$-$" be any negative real number. It should be clear that:

$$\frac{+}{+} > 0;\ \ \frac{-}{-} > 0$$
$$\frac{+}{-} < 0;\ \ \frac{-}{+} < 0$$

If you can figure out for which values of $x$ has $(x+3)$ positive\negative, and which values of $x$ make $(x-4)$ positive\negative, can you use the above rules to figure out where the fraction is negative?

Comment: I have to think about this one for a second. I see what you are saying.

Comment: Thank you I understand. @jameselmore

Comment: @AlexanderJohn, no prob :)

Answer (score 1):

we have only two cases:
a) $$x\geq -3$$ and $$x<4$$
or
b) $$x\le -3$$ and $$x>4$$ and this is impossible.
Thus we have $$-3\le x<4$$